# Using a domain name for a website

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, dns, domain-name

I know this should be a pretty easy thing to do, but I'm having trouble.

Say I bought a domain name from 123-reg.co.uk "example12345.com". And I have a website hosted on AWS called something like http://lowcost-env.blahblahblah.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/.

I have read the following blog: https://www.thesitewizard.com/domain/point-domain-name-website.shtml and followed the steps, but still have 2 issues/questions:

1) I have configured "web forwarding" on 123-reg.com to forward requests to example.com to my convoluted AWS address, but when I type in example12345.com to a browser, it just says the DNS can't find that domain name. I set this up weeks ago, and did manage to see it work a couple of times, but weeks later it doesn't work anymore.

2) On the occasions I did see the web forwarding working, I notice that the browser displays the convoluted AWS address after the redirect happens. Is there a way to configure it so that users type in example12345.com into the browser, and then it's that address that is always displayed in the browser address bar whilst they are browsing around my website? Surely I need more than just web forwarding and a redirect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Route53 for pointing domain name to the AWS endpoint. Check the step 5 of this documentation :
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/getting-started.html

In Route53 you can point your domain to alias whereas in other DNS you need to specify IP address/CNAME. As in your case you are using endpoint from AWS you can map it to your domain.

You will also need to modify the nameservers to point to AWS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any idea how to upload an elastic beanstalk website (or associate one) with the newly created bucket?

Comment: Sorry I'm not too sure about mapping S3 bucket and beanstalk. I found an article to create custom domain name for beanstalk. You can have look at : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstarts/latest/webapp/expanding-environments.html?icmpid=docs_eb_console_new#expanding-environments-domain